# What is the default timeout for AngularJS $http service requests?

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, connection-timeout

In [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) it does not mention which is the default timeout in case of undefined.

How can I know which is the default value for this configuration?

Comment: there is no timeout by default

Comment: So the http connection stays open undefinitely? I'm seeing [ClientAbortException](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ClientAbortException.html) on the server side. So the only possibility is that the client is leaving the site, isn't it?

Comment: I think you have an internal timeout set by the browser to prevent leaks or attacks, not really sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At one time the default timeout for http requests was 30 seconds, but now many browsers perform "keep-alive" polling by default so in all practicality there isn't one. I've had http requests sit for several minutes before the server itself finally gave up and issued a timeout.

Comment: I observe that requests sits for around 2 minutes until marked as timed out on ff57.