# Showing failed response in Angular Js after waiting more than 30 second from an API response

Tags: php, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. I have payment section in my PHP project where payment response from the API is displayed in the frond-end using AngularJs.

The issue is, when the API response exceeds more that 30 seconds suddenly the default error message triggers. But in backed, the payments are doing fine and database is updating perfectly with a success message.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check url:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547229/what-is-the-default-timeout-for-angularjs-http-service-requests

Comment: couldn't help it, again the same error.

Comment: I this issue is not browser dependent, is there any timeout option with angularJS.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments check for timeout here

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the maximum execution time limit is set to 30 seconds. Increase the maximum execution time by using the below steps

1. Open the `path/to/php/php.ini` file in editor, if you are using xampp then the path will be `xampp/php/php.ini`
2. Find this in the php.ini file `max_execution_time=30`
3. Replace it with `max_execution_time=180` or any time limit you want

Comment: `max_execution_time` is already set to `30000` but again fails.

Comment: Check phpinfo to ensure the max_execution_time is increased. If not increased then try restarting the apache server.

Comment: `max_execution_time` is set and server restarted, but issue not fixed.
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767148/failure-in-getting-continuous-api-response-from-php-in-angularjs`

Comment: Which payment gateway you are using?

Comment: `Westpac PayWay` but payment gateway responds and while performing the DB operations angularJs displays the error.

Comment: Maybe the return url redirection causing this. To ensure that just create a php file with the script in below comment and call it from angular if it works fine then the payment gateway redirection is the problem

Comment: <?php
echo date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
sleep(35);
echo date('h:i:s');
?>