# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from PHP in AngularJs

Tags: php, angularjs, cross-browser, http-post

I have payment section in my PHP project where payment response from the API is displayed in the frond-end using AngularJs. CURL is used for calling payment API from PHP end. After getting the response from payment API, I am updating the Database accordingly.

The issue what i found is, I haven't continuously getting the API response in the angular side even-if all the backed functionalities are working properly.

I have checked with many browser network tab, but in every failure case i have't got a response, but back-end DB is updating properly.

Also in every success and failure case (failure means, Not getting response in angularjs HTTP POST request ), I have logged the  JSON response in the PHP side (Which is going to send to angular side as response) seems similar in both cases.

For additional information:
In network tab, header section, there is no response header coming, for the error case. So its not triggering the then block of angularjs http post, instead its triggering the error block, as there is no response. 
And in console tab its showing “net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE” for that failing request url.

Does anyone have any idea about why am i not getting response in angular side randomly ?

Comment: check in chrome network tab what you posting and getting

Comment: I have already checked chrome network tab for the same request, if i get a response it works fine, If not, it fails.

Comment: You need to add some response for failure also then

Comment: I am handling success and failure case in my PHP side, But sometimes i am not getting any response in front end angular side, even i am passing same response from PHP.

Comment: There is no failure case in back-end, if error case occurred it works fine in both front-end and back-end. But in success case back-end operations are performing well but not always getting response in frond-end,that's the issue .

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
By setting `Http verbs - options` solved my issue. Also disabling the proxy server helps.